# How to include a hyperlink in a label in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, hyperlink

I'm trying to find a simple way to include a hyperlink within the text of a label in my iOS app.  The goal is to have the user tap the URL and the app will open a Safari browser with that URL.

I've read about including a button with the URL as the label, but that's not going to work for my application.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`NSArrtibutedStrings`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) — but I would recommend to use some wrapper around this C-functions. I like [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

The demo included shows exactly, how hyperlinks can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Safari you could start a UIWebView. You have more control about the actions the user can do at that web page.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about using the UIWebView.  However, I'm still stuck with how to include the hyperlink within the text of the label to ultimately launch either Safari or UIWebView

Comment: I think ott-- was suggesting you use a UIWebView with your own local HTML as a way to create the hyperlink.

Comment: Do you really want the (sometimes cryptic) URL on the label? You could put "visit xyz-Website" there instead. That would be the description, where the URL is hidden to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interactions for your label and then override the `- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method to handle the touch.

To enable user interactions set the following property on your UILabel:

```
urlLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

An example of touchedEnded:WihEvent: in your UIViewController:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch  * touch;
   CGPoint    currPt;

   if ((touches = [event touchesForView:urlLabel]))
   {
      touch = [touches anyObject];
      currPt  = [touch locationInView:self.view];
      if ( (currPt.x >= urlLabel.frame.origin.x) &&
           (currPt.y >= urlLabel.frame.origin.y) &&
           (currPt.x <= (urlLabel.frame.origin.x + urlLabel.frame.size.width)) &&
           (currPt.y <= (urlLabel.frame.origin.y + urlLabel.frame.size.height)) )
      {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLabel.text]];
         return;
      };
   };

   return;
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP. How would a check look like, if a touch occurs on a hyperlink within the text or not?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I was making (probably the incorrect) assumption that the UILabel only contained the URL. I've updated the example to limit  the action to only touches that begin and end within the UILabel view.

Comment: But this won't identify a touch on a hyperlink among other text on one label. And instead of subclassing UILabel you should use a UIGestureRecognizer.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Like I mentioned previously, the example does not separate URL text from non-URL text, but assumes the entire UILabel is contains only URL text (I realize now that this is probably not what the original poster was requesting). On a side note, the above example does not sub-class UILabel.  The method touchedEnded:WihEvent: is added to the UIViewController class of the current super view.

Comment: I know, that a view controller is also a UIResponder, as a UIView is as-well. But your answer isn't clear about this. And a gesture recognizer is the best solution, as it's only task is to recognize gestures — it helps to write cleaner, reusable and easier maintainable code. Nevertheless your post is not answering the question and must be considered wrong.